# Trabalhando com vetores / matrizes

Tags: c#, array, lista, arraylist

Olá, tenho a seguinte dúvida, eu tenho 5 vetores

```
string[] Defesa = { "Gigante", "Golem", "Gigante Real" };

string[] AtkTorre = { "Corredor", "Ariete de Batalha", "Gigante Real" };

string[] AP = { "Bárbaros de Elite", "Gigante Real", "P.E.K.K.A" };

string[] Sup = { "Bruxa", "Príncipe", "Mosqueteira", "Três Mosqueteiras", "Bruxa Sombria", "Lançador", "Caçador", "Executor", "Carrinho de Canhão" };

string[] C = { "Torre Inferno", "Canhão" };
```

Eu gostaria, de acessá-las a partir de um outro vetor, por exemplo:

```
string[] vetor = { Defesa, AtkTorre, AP, Sup, C };
string valor = vetor[0][1]; // Golem
```

Já tentei com lista, array, matriz.. E nada funciona... Eu gostaria de saber se tem como.. E como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note que a sua variável vetor não é um array string, mas sim um array de objetos
E para recuperar o valor é preciso tratá- da forma adequada. Ou de fato utilizar uma matriz através da declaração `string[][]`.

```
string[] Defesa = { "Gigante", "Golem", "Gigante Real" };
string[] AtkTorre = { "Corredor", "Ariete de Batalha", "Gigante Real" };
string[] AP = { "Bárbaros de Elite", "Gigante Real", "P.E.K.K.A" };
string[] Sup = { "Bruxa", "Príncipe", "Mosqueteira", "Três Mosqueteiras", "Bruxa Sombria", "Lançador", "Caçador", "Executor", "Carrinho de Canhão" };
string[] C = { "Torre Inferno", "Canhão" };

object[] vetor = { Defesa, AtkTorre, AP, Sup, C };
string valor = ((vetor[0] as string[])[1]); //Golem

string[][] matriz = { Defesa, AtkTorre, AP, Sup, C };
string valorMatriz = matriz[0][1]; //Golem
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Só precisei adicionar um [] no string[], e sumiu todos os erros, e eu quebrando a cabeça aqui uhahahah, agradeço de vdd pela ajuda :)))

Answer (score 4):

O que você quer fazer é de fato uma estrutura de dados de Matrix. O que você precisa entender melhor é que o acesso à matriz deve ser feito não através do nome do vetor daquela posição, mas sim através do vetor em si.

```
string[] vetor = { Defesa, AtkTorre, AP, Sup, C };
```

Nessa linha você criou um vetor, não uma matriz, por isso não é possível acessar uma dimensão a mais desse vetor. Para criar a matriz de fato, seria algo como:

```
string[][] vetor = { { "Gigante", "Golem", "Gigante Real" }, { "Corredor", "Ariete de Batalha", "Gigante Real" }, { "Bárbaros de Elite", "Gigante Real", "P.E.K.K.A" }, { "Bruxa", "Príncipe", "Mosqueteira", "Três Mosqueteiras", "Bruxa Sombria", "Lançador", "Caçador", "Executor", "Carrinho de Canhão" }, { "Torre Inferno", "Canhão" } };
```

Com isso, você poderia acessar o elemento `Golem` da matriz:

```
string valorMatriz = vetor[0][1]; //Golem
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Abriu minha mente <3